# DataBricks API Powershell

Tags: powershell, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm having an issue using the databricks api 2.0

The invoke-rest method fails for the following error:
"Error 400 io.jsonwebtoken.IncorrectClaimException: Expected aud claim to be: https://management.core.windows.net/, but was:
https://management.azure.com."

I followed the instructions in the microsoft docs.

```
cls

$DataBrick = <DataBrickURL>

$DataBricksResourceID = <ResourceID>

$VaultName = <KeyVault>
$KeyName = <Key>

$apiEndpointUri = "https://management.azure.com"  
$tenantId = <TenantID>  
$applicationId = <ApplicationID> 
$secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName -Name $KeyName -AsPlainText

$RequestAccessTokenUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/token"
$body = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$applicationId&client_secret=$encodedSecret&resource=2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d" 
$Managementbody = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$applicationId&client_secret=$encodedSecret&resource=$apiEndpointUri"  
$contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 

$AccessToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $RequestAccessTokenUri -Body $body -ContentType $contentType  
Write-Output $AccessToken
$ManagementToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $RequestAccessTokenUri -Body $Managementbody -ContentType $contentType
Write-Output $Token

$apiuri = $DataBrick +"/api/2.0/clusters/get"
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + $AccessToken.access_token)
$headers.Add("X-Databricks-Azure-SP-Management-Token", $ManagementToken.access_token)
$headers.Add("X-Databricks-Azure-Workspace-Resource-Id", $DataBricksResourceID)

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiuri -Headers $headers
```

Answer (score 0):

AS per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token#--get-the-azure-management-resource-endpoint-token), `resource` parameter (your `apiEndpointUri` variable) should be `https://management.core.windows.net/`, but you have `https://management.azure.com`

Answer (score 0):

Based on e.g. mentioned in Question, There are following steps are happening:

1. Get a token from Microsoft login service for provided resource id of databircks.
2. Get a management Token. In your e.g., it is provided as "https://management.azure.com" which is not correct. You needs to use "https://management.core.windows.net/" which is mentioned in error response too. You can refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token#--api-access-for-service-principals-that-are-not-workspace-users for reference which is not for Powershell but useful enough to understand authentication flow
3. Using both tokens, to call Databricks APIs

In short, if you correct apiEndpointUri based on error. It should work provided other details are correct and have correct permission configured.

Comment: Yeah now I'm getting a different error when trying to get the management token
"AADSTS500011: The resource principal named 
https://management.core.azure.com was not found in the tenant named <tenantid>. This can happen 
if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You 
might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant"

Comment: It seems you have not provided correct service principal Id for client_id in request. What are you setting for applicationId  ?

Comment: I copied it directly from the app registration the the service principle was set up in, from the portal.  I know those two items are correct.  Otherwise it would have failed just getting the access token.  But that worked.  Just when trying to get the management token does that error happen.

Comment: Only other possibility is DatabricksResourceID is not correct or don't have access to provided tenant. Based on documentation this is the format: /subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/<workspace-name>

Comment: Yeah I have access to both.  I'm owner of every subscription we have.

Comment: It's a sole issue with https://management.core.azure.com
It's not because of my access or the IDs in the code

Comment: right, check it out this link https://www.koskila.net/how-to-fix-aadsts50011-the-resource-principal-named-was-not-found-in-the-tenant/ , if not done already. it has some cases covered to troubleshoot if anything related to your misconfiguration of app